# When using SSRS in Local Mode with no user interaction, is it possible to get more detailed error messages?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Using SSRS 2008 R2

I have a background process that dynamically generates RDL for report generation. I am using SSRS in LocalMode with no user interaction or connections to the SQL Server Reporting Services. The only thing the user will ever see will be the final PDF.

I am using the Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.Render to generate the report.

When an error occurs, the only message that gets returned is something like the following:

```
    Warning: An error occurred while executing the subreport 'SUBREPORT_000005' (Instance: 0): The definition of the report '' is invalid. (rsErrorExecutingSubreport)
    Warning: Warnings occurred while executing the subreport ‘SUBREPORT_000005’. (rsWarningExecutingSubreport)
```

These errors are obviously not very useful. In order to get the real error, I have to save all the reports to the disk and open the offending report in Report Builder 3.0, modify it to provide everything it needs and then execute the report. At this point, Report Builder will report a more detailed error such as Missing Fields, invalid syntax on formulas etc. This process is time consuming and slows down the debugging cycle.

Is there a way to configure the LocalReport to give me the more detailed error? The local report has a property called ShowDetailedSubreportMessages, but it makes no difference in the errors that it returns.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked this in other forums and so far it appears that this is not currently possible. So a manual approach through Report Builder seems to be the answer still.